# Help with proof of Root Test.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove the case,

Let $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = L>1$ then the series $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ is divergent.

My Attempt :

Let $r$ be a number such that $L>r>1$ and as $|a_n|^{1/n} \to L$ as $n \to ∞$ then there exists an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n≥m, |a_n|^{1/n}>r>1 \Rightarrow |a_n|> r^n$ and $ \displaystyle\sum r^n$ diverges so by comparison test $\displaystyle\sum |a_n|$ diverges.

Now how do I prove that $\displaystyle\sum a_n $ diverges?

Also if there are any mistakes in my prove, do point out. Thanks.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Correct me if I'm wrong, the contrapositive will be "If $L>1$ then $\sum a_n$ is NOT convergent. But it still doesn't prove that it is divergent as $\sum a_n$ is not necessarily a series of positive terms right? ...

Comment: My fault : I thought divergent is the same as "not convergent", I think that is a mistake. If divergent means going to plus/minus infinity then we will need a different argument.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг No worries, that is exactly what's been bothering me. I have two Real Analysis books. In one they have mentioned Root Test with series of positive terms which is straightforward as you don't have absolute values. But in the other book and also on the internet, I found this, and I've been racking my brains ever since only to make sense out of this.

Comment: I agree with you. However, if you are for example taking a course, then your teacher should have the final say in this matter. This business has been bothering me a bit : when it comes up in a conversation I just clarify the meaning with whoever brought it up and move on, relieved that my teacher stuck with divergent meaning "not convergent" in my days.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг No unfortunately I don't have teachers at all, I'm just self studying from different books, it's hard to understand everything on your own, but I'm glad I'm born in the age of Internet.

Comment: Yes, I am glad for you as well. Coming back to the question, do you have issues with the first answer by user1828958? It does not seem to assume that divergence is the opposite of convergence, for example.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$

for a given $n>k$ and $\epsilon >0$ arbitrary small

$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} >\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} L - \epsilon \geq \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} 1 =  \infty $

Comment: Please set a good mark for a good answer.